# Nestjs throws a TS2322 err using the examples

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm new to nest and I have run into an error which is not really decodable for me. I tried to follow the [nest example](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/05-sql-typeorm/src), but no luck.

```
 [tsl] ERROR in /Users/user/Documents/development/sprinta/src/server/app.module.ts(12,5)
[0]       TS2322: Type '(DynamicModule | typeof ProjectModule)[]' is not assignable to type 'Type<any> | DynamicModule | Promise<DynamicModule> | ForwardReference<any>'.
[0]   Type '(DynamicModule | typeof ProjectModule)[]' is not assignable to type 'ForwardReference<any>'.
[0]     Property 'forwardRef' is missing in type '(DynamicModule | typeof ProjectModule)[]'.
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AngularUniversalModule } from './modules/angular-universal/angular-universal.module';
import { JiraService } from './services/jira.service'
// modules
import { ProjectModule } from './resources/local/projects/project.module'
// sync
import {ProjectsSync} from './sync/projects.sync'

@Module({
  imports: [
    [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(), ProjectModule],
    AngularUniversalModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers:[JiraService, ProjectsSync],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

project.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ProjectService } from './project.service';
import { ProjectController } from './project.controller';
import { Project } from './project.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Project])],
  providers: [ProjectService],
  controllers: [ProjectController],
})
export class ProjectModule {}
```

project.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Project } from './project.entity';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Project)
    private readonly projectRepository: Repository<Project>,
  ) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<Project[]> {
    return await this.projectRepository.find();
  }
}
```

project.entity.ts

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Project {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 500 })
  name: string;
}
```

project.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ProjectService } from './project.service';
import { Project } from './project.entity';

@Controller('project')
export class ProjectController {
  constructor(private readonly projectService: ProjectService) {}

  @Get()
  findAll(): Promise<Project[]> {
    return this.projectService.findAll();
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra nested array around `TypeOrmModule.forRoot()` and `ProjectModule`.  The `@Module` call should read:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(), ProjectModule,
    AngularUniversalModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers:[JiraService, ProjectsSync],
})
```

Comment: I tried and it brought up the following error: [Nest] 1593   - 11/18/2018, 9:03:11 PM   [ExceptionHandler] No repository for "Project" was found. Looks like this

Comment: No, forRoot should only be used in the AppModule. The syntax of `imports:  [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Project])]` is perfectly correct for additional modules